# Number of Papers for Doctor of Science (DSc)

Tags: phd

I am a young scientist working in India after finishing Masters in Physics. In last three years of employment, I have co-authored around 12 papers so far. I am interested in going for D.Sc. I have seen some universities award DSc after Masters also, But I am not sure how many minimum number of  papers will be required to get D.Sc. Do you all have any idea ?. I may also apply from a abroad university.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That will depend on the course you enroll in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not all papers are created equal, I don't think that there is any minimum number other than one. It might also depend a lot on your contributions to co-authored papers. It also depends on field and Physics isn't mine. Finally, it depends a lot on where you are. In the US it would likely be very different from UK or India, for example.

Note that some fields/places tend to award a doctorate over an accumulation of work over several years/papers/projects. Others, it is primarily awarded on a specific dissertation and little else but qualifying examinations.

But the way to know if you qualify or are able to move quickly to your goal, you will need to ask someone at a particular university in a particular place.